# Running a forEach() on an Array of Objects After Retrieving with findOne() in Mongo Back-end

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I am using findOne() to retrieve a document like this:

```
  let staffToUpdate = await Staff.findOne({
    _id: request.parameters.id
  }).exec();

  let historyArray = await crewToUpdate.history;

  console.log("historyArray: ", await historyArray);

  console.log(Array.isArray(historyArray)); // returns true
```

The data looks like this:

```
history: [
  {
   status: "active",
   startDate: <Date>,
   endDate: <Date>, 
   completed: false
  },
  {
   status: "training",
   startDate: <Date>,
   endDate: <Date>, 
   completed: true
  }
]
```

When I do the above I get an array of objects printed out, as well as a return of "true" on the check to see if "historyArray" is indeed an array.

So now that I have this array, I'd like to run a transformation on the objects found within it, like so:

```
  let updatedHistoryArray = historyArray.then(
    updatedHistoryArray.forEach(history => {
      history.completed = true;
      history.endDate = new Date();
    })
  );
```

However, this is the part that's not working. When I try this I get this error:

> Reason: ReferenceError: historyArray is not defined

What am I missing here?

UPDATE: After a suggestion from a commenter below, I tried this:

```
  let staffToUpdate = await Staff.findOne({
    _id: request.parameters.id
  }).exec();

  let staffObject = staffToUpdate.toObject();

  let historyArray = await staffObject.history;

  console.log(await historyArray); // prints the array

  console.log(Array.isArray(historyArray)); // returns true

  historyArray.forEach(history => { // this is where the error occurs
    history.completed = true;
    history.endDate = new Date();
  });
```

With this last block of code I get this error:

> Reason: ReferenceError: historyArray is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`historyArray` is not a Promise and you can not run `then` on it. 
When this code runs

```
let staffToUpdate = await Staff.findOne({
    _id: request.parameters.id
}).exec();
```

it waits until query is executed and assigns **the actual result (mongoose Document), not a promise** and assigns it to `staffToUpdate`. You need to run `toObject()` on mongoose Document to get plain object without the wrapper:

```
const unwrappedStaffToUpdate = staffToUpdate.toObject();
```

After that you don't need to use `await` on `crewToUpdate.history` because it is not a Promise and it is synchronious. That is why you can not run `then` on `historyArray` because it is a normal Array and not a Promise.

Try this code:

```
unwrappedStaffToUpdate.historyArray.forEach(history => {
      history.completed = true;
      history.endDate = new Date();
});
```

Or if you do not want to mutate your Array use `map` instead of `forEach`:

```
const updatedHistoryArray = unwrappedStaffToUpdate.historyArray.map(history => ({
          ...history 
          completed: true;
          endDate: new Date()
      })
);
```

Comment: When I run the first option you describe I get the same exact error: `Reason: ReferenceError: historyArray is not defined`

Comment: Forgot to mention that you need to run `toObject()` on the returned Document in order to get plain object without mongoose wrapper - `staffToUpdate.toObject()`

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: I don't see the `toObject()` in your code. Did you update it?

Comment: I make the change to use toObject() to ensure I have a plain JS object, but still getting the same error: `Reason: ReferenceError: historyArray is not defined`

Comment: Can you post your code? It seems that something else is wrong

Comment: What do you get when you run `console.log(historyArray)`?

Comment: [  { status: 'inactive',
    _id: 5tf768de3078410728386f0b,
    completed: false,
    startDate: 'Mon Oct 29 2018 16:08:58 GMT-0400 (EDT)' },
  { status: 'training',
    _id: 4fd76de7cc032f086790a84s,
    completed: false,
    startDate: 'Mon Oct 29 2018 16:30:31 GMT-0400 (EDT)' } ]

Comment: So its an Array with a value, it can not be undefined. Are you sure you'he posted all the code connected with the issue?

Comment: Yup. I have posted all the code. My guess is that it's `undefined` because something is asynchronous.

Comment: But it is defined one line above when you try to log it. How can it become `undefined`? Maybe there are some side-effects that some other part of the code is performing and sets this array to undefined?

Comment: Found a simple syntax glitch that was the problem. Thanks, this worked.